# ODE Gauss test convergence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, ordinary-differential-equations, convergence-divergence

Consider the differential equation:
$$(1 - x^2)\frac{d^2y}{dx^2} - 2 x \frac{dy}{dx} + ky = 0$$
where $k$ is an arbitrary real number.

Plugging in the power series:
$$y(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{c_n x^n}$$
we find
$$c_{n+2}=\frac{n(n + 1) - k}{(n + 2)(n + 1)} c_n$$

which yields two linearly independent basis functions:

$$y(x)= c_0\bigg(1 -  \frac{k}{2!}x^2 - \frac{k(6 - k)}{4!} x^4 + ...\bigg)+c_1\bigg(x + \frac{(2 - k)}{3!} x^3 + \frac{(2 - k)(12 - k)}{5!} x^5 + ...\bigg)$$

By the ratio test, the radius of convergence of each basis function is 1.

We could use the Gauss test to test for convergence of each basis function on the radius of the circle of convergence i.e. when $|x|=1$:

$$\frac{t_n}{t_{n+1}} = \frac{c_n x^n}{c_{n+2} x^{n+2}} = \frac{(n+2)(n+1)}{(n(n+1)-k)x^2}=\frac{n^2+3n+2}{n^2+n-k}=\frac{n^2+n-k+2n+2+k}{n^2+n-k} = 1+\frac{2n+2+k}{n^2+n-k}=1+\frac{2n+2-2k+3k}{n^2+n-k} = 1+\frac{2}{n}+\frac{3k}{n^2+n-k} = 1 + \frac{2}{n} + O(1/n^2)$$

By Gauss test we consider the coefficient of the $\frac{1}{n}$ term which in this case is 2. Since $2>1$, by the Gauss test, the series **converges**.

The result I am getting as specified by the rubric is incorrect, and the series is supposed to **diverge** on $|x|=1$. I checked the series on Mathematica which also seems to indicate that the function diverges on $|x|=1$. What is wrong with my analysis?